# Symfony 3 does not set remember me cookie

Tags: php, symfony, cookies, remember-me

I am following [How to Add "Remember Me" Login Functionality](http://symfony.com/doc/3.2/security/remember_me.html), which should be straight forward, but not so.

I also checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10958187/symfony2-remember-me-token-is-not-set), among others.

I checked that the login form is correctly posting the field `_remember_me`, but Symfony somehow is not intercepting it and creating the cookie.

I went to the class that, I believe, sets the cookie, `/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/RememberMe/TokenBasedRememberMeService.php`, and it seems that nothing is happening over there. I tried to var_dump or put on a session variable some of the arguments that build the cookie, to no avail.

The login as such is working properly.

I am using Guard Authenticator.

Here's the code:

security.yml

```
security:
encoders:
    UsedBundle\Entity\User: 
        algorithm: bcrypt
providers:
    db_provider:
        entity:
            class: UsedBundle:User
            property: email
            manager_name: used

firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    main:
        anonymous: ~
        provider: db_provider
        form_login: 
            login_path: /
            username_parameter: _email
            check_path: /login_check
            use_referer: true
        guard:
            authenticators:
                - app.form_login_authenticator 
        logout:
            path:   /logout
            target: /
        remember_me:
            secret: '%secret%'
            secure: false #change this to true if HTTPS
access_control:
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

The login form:

```
{% if error is defined and error is not null %}
{{ dump(error) }}

<div>{{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security') }}</div>
{% else %}
<form action="" method="post" name="login_form" id="login_form" >
    <div class="contact" >
        <input type="email" id="email" name="_email" class="form-control" placeholder="e-mail" value="{% if last_username is defined %}{{ last_username }} {% endif %}" />
    </div>
    <div class="contact" >
        <input type="password" id="password" name="_password" placeholder="mot de passe" />
    </div>
    <div id="captcha_signup"></div>
    <div id="remember_me">
        <label for="remember">Se souvenir de moi </label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="remember_me" name="_remember_me" />
        <p id="a_recovery">mot de passe oubliée?</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button type="submit" class="sub_ok btn" name="submit" >Valider</button>
    </div>
</form>  
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your custom authenticator that extends either `AbstractGuardAuthenticator` or `AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator` needs to `return true;` in `supportsRememberMe()`

```
public function supportsRememberMe()
{
    return true;
}
```

If your code already has this in it, please share your full authenticator implementation and output from dev.log from the moment you go to the login page and hit that submit button.